# Which OSX library to link against (command line) to use NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, macos, clang

I want to compile and link an application from the command line on MAC OSX using the command-line compiler.  I have a source file named "hello.m" as follows:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        NSLog(@"hello world\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

At the command prompt, I type:

```
    $ clang -o hello hello.m
```

But the compiler returns:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_NSLog", referenced from:
          _main in main-74f615.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Obviously, I need to link against a library when I call NSLog.  Which library do I need to link with?

Comment: Did you try adding `-framework Foundation` to the clang command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The library you need to link to is 'Foundation'. That's the framework you're importing at the top of the file. If this were in Xcode, it sets up framework linking for you via project settings / automation framework detection. When using clang directly, you need to pass the `-framework` flag to properly link to them.

```
clang -framework Foundation -o hello hello.m
```

Comment: Ok so what exactly does "-framework Foundation" do?  Does it link against a whole set of libraries?  Is there not a single ".a" library that I can just specify on the command-line?

Comment: Under the covers, a framework is a package that contains a dynamic library (or a static one in some cases), plus resources. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html. So -framework is a way of telling it to link to the 'Foundation' library, which is contained within the framework